# How to use filtering with restful controller in laravel4

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 . I want to filter routes in a way that only login page will be opened before users are logged in . Here i am using auth for login. Login page view name is login.

My routes.php code is as follows :

```
   Route::controller('users', 'UsersEventbotController');
Route::controller('eventbotmenu', 'EventbotMenuController');
```

I am doing it like this :

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
Route::controller('users', 'UsersEventbotController');
Route::controller('eventbotmenu', 'EventbotMenuController');
});
```

But this method is not allowing login page to open , because its inside  UsersEventbotController controller .

Please help me on this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route the login action outside of the Route filter group.

```
Route::get('users/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersEventbotController@getLogin'));
Route::post('users/login', array('as' => 'post-login', 'uses' => 'UsersEventbotController@postLogin'));
Route::get('users/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'UsersEventbotController@getLogout'));

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('users', 'UsersEventbotController');
    Route::controller('eventbotmenu', 'EventbotMenuController');
});
```